# not sure whats causing these errors

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 #import "ViewController.h"




@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I'm not sure what I changed or how to fix these errors:

Cannot find interface declaration for 'ViewController';
View controller cannot use 'super because it is not a root class

Comment: What does your ViewController.h file look like?

Comment: it just has #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you forgot to sub-class UIViewController (check your header):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

Comment: Thank You this fixed it!